# MAC OS X: How to determine if filesystem is case sensitive?

Tags: api, macos, filesystems, case-sensitive

I have used the [statfs(2)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/statfs.2.html%23//apple_ref/doc/man/2/statfs) system call to get many characteristics of a Mac OS X filesystem, but it doesn't tell me if the filesystem is case-sensitive or not.

I need this information as the application I am developing will be moving many files around and I want to detect potential loss of data due to files being moved from a case-**sensitive** filesystem to a case-**insensitive** filesystem.

Can anyone suggest a way of detecting this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're already using `stat(2)`, then you can easily use [`pathconf(2)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/pathconf.2.html) with the `_PC_CASE_SENSITIVE` selector (result `0` = case-insensitve, `1` = case-sensitive.  Note that the man page is out of date, but the `_PC_CASE_SENSITIVE` and `_PC_CASE_PRESERVING` are supported. By convention, if a file system doesn't support `_PC_CASE_SENSITIVE` selector then it is case-sensitive.

Comment: http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2007/Apr/msg00036.html suggests that that's not reliable.

Answer (score 9):

<strike>I’ve looked around and haven’t found an API for that. There are two possibilities I can think of:</strike>

- Creating a temporary file and trying to open it with a different case pattern, e.g. creating "a9999" and trying to open "A9999". Considering that neither "a9999" nor "A9999" were available on that particular directory, the filesystem is case-sensitive if and only if opening "A9999" fails.
- Running `diskutil(8)` against the filesystem. It reports case-sensitive, -insensitive file systems differently: `Name: Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive)` vs. `Name: Mac OS Extended` (not journaled).

Since `diskutil(8)` is able to identify that, it could be the case that this information is available via some API or system call.

---

**Edit:** It turns out that `NSURL` has a set of methods that work on file system properties. In particular, `-getResourceValue:forKey:error` with the key being `NSURLVolumeSupportsCaseSensitiveNamesKey` will tell you whether a given filesystem (represented as an `NSURL` instance) supports case sensitive names.

See the following code for an example of its use.

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

  NSString *path = [NSString stringWithCString:argv[1] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
  NSURL *filesystem = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:YES];

  NSNumber *caseSensitiveFS;
  BOOL hasCaseSensitiveResource;

  hasCaseSensitiveResource = [filesystem getResourceValue:&caseSensitiveFS
    forKey:NSURLVolumeSupportsCaseSensitiveNamesKey error:NULL];

  if (hasCaseSensitiveResource)
  {
    if ([caseSensitiveFS intValue] == 1)
    {
      NSLog(@"%s is a case sensitive filesystem", argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
      NSLog(@"%s is a case insensitive filesystem", argv[1]);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"can't query %s for case sensitiveness", argv[1]);
  }

  [pool drain];
  return 0;
}
```

Output example:

```
./testcase /
/ is a case insensitive filesystem

./testcase /Volumes/Disk\ Image/
/Volumes/Disk Image/ is a case sensitive filesystem

./testcase nonono
can't query nonono for case sensitiveness
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using C++, not Objective-C; is there a C/C++ solution?

Comment: Actually thinking about it, this might be the most usable solution - there is no reason why I couldn't use this in my application.

Comment: @trojanfoe Now that I know of. Even if libfs is not readily available, you could try to use the source code of FSFormatName.c as pointed out in Ken’s answer. It looks like it’s just reading a few blocks and, for what it’s worth, <hfs/hfs_format.h> is available under /usr/include.

Comment: I don't really know Objective-C so I cannot get the above code to be called from my C++ (I've looked at a question on SO about this subject but I requires a reference to the Objective-C object in order to work)...

Comment: @trojanfoe I’m not sure what your problem is. For what it’s worth, you can easily convert the `main()` function above to a standard C function that accepts the mount point string as its only parameter and returns an integer that covers the three cases (case sensitive, case insensitive, query failed). Build an object file with the definition of the function, declare it in a header file, include the header file as extern "C" in your C++ code, link the object file with the rest of your code.

Comment: Ah indeed!  It's now working - I was under the mistaken assumption that I needed to implement a Objective-C class!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Create a temporary file with uppercase letters and check if the file exists using lowercase letters, if the test fails the file system *is* case-sensitive.

Comment: Yeah that would probably work - seems a little crude though :)

Comment: Nope, its also a cross platform solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Look here for some code to find the HFS subtype of a device:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libfs/libfs-3/FSFormatName.c

The routine is_hfs will return the hfs subtype. If the subtype is kHFSXSubType or kHFSXJSubType, then it's an HFSX (case sensitive) device.

Comment: I haven’t been able to find libfs on my system, though. And it looks like none of the system libraries exports the functions declared in FSFormatName.h.

Comment: Excellent; many thanks.  Is there anything more generic that covers other filesystem types?

Comment: @Bavarious: I'm not suggesting that routine in an available library. I'm saying to use that code as an example for how to do what he needs to do.

Comment: @Ken It’d be nice if libfs were available, though. At any rate, that code uses header files and functions not available on stock Mac OS 10.6, namely `getblk()` and `getwrapper()`, which apparently should be declared in `<sys/buf.h>` and are not available on any library under `/usr/lib`. I haven’t investigated this further because of those `NSURL` methods that do the job.