# Are the UNIX Command Line Tools like Cygwin exactly the same as real Unix/Linux?

Tags: windows, unix, cygwin

If there is no difference, then I can just install Cygwin on my Windows 7 PC, and seems there's no need to buy a Macbook (as I can use UNIX command line already).

Comment: The Cygwin command line tools are close to the same as on Unix/Linux.  However, there are some differences, such as symbolic links (not really existent on Windows).  You can do a lot with Cygwin assuming that they're the same on Windows as on Unix. It depends on what you're seeking to test with the thought of buying a Mac.  Mac OS X is a BSD-based system; it is related to, but different from, Linux. You  can run Linux in a VM on your Windows 7 machine, or you could run Windows 7 in a VM on a Macbook, and you could run Linux in a VM on the Macbook too. (I run Linux, but not Windows, on my Mac).

Comment: Also note that there are differences in commands between 'Unix' and 'Linux', too.  For example, `mv` on Linux (GNU `mv`) supports an option `-t target-dir` that is not supported on Mac OS X, nor on most non-Linux versions of Unix.

Comment: @Jonathan, thx, I plan to run Linux VM on my mac for PHP development(install LAMP environment in Linux VM,  is the configuration for Mac's communication with Linux VM hard to do?)

Comment: It's not very hard as long as you're careful.  That said, I seem to have been insufficiently careful - some upgrade to the hosted (guest) OS has broken the previously working connectivity to the Mac OS X (that is, the mounting of a portion of the Mac OS X drive on the guest OS).  I'm not sure whether that was something I screwed up, or whether the problem is really of someone else's making.  I've gotta figure that out sometime.  In the interim, I may end up creating a new VM and starting over.

Comment: Why not run a Linux VM on your existing Windows 7 PC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are differences. You just have the basic commands like `cd`, `ls` etc but of course nothing compared to a real operating system.
You can read more about what is or not Cywin at its homepage:
https://www.cygwin.com/.

Answer (score 0):

No - the [Cygwin FAQ](https://cygwin.com/faq.html) lists a number of differences from Linux/Unix.

It does share one difference with OSX versus almost every other system: as a rule, the underlying filenames are case-insensitive but the tools lack flexibility to deal with this except for special cases (though for both, case-sensitivity is being offered as a feature now).

The Cygwin FAQ mentions [this](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.case-sensitive).  OSX has supported it for a while, though it is not the default (see [MAC OS X: How to determine if filesystem is case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706215/mac-os-x-how-to-determine-if-filesystem-is-case-sensitive)).